# Compartir el ratón de mi computadora con Android

Tags: java, android

Quiero compartir el ratón de mi computadora con *Android*, como lo hace el programa de **DeskDock**.

Intenté usando **DeskDock** pero al tenerlo abierto no me permite mandar más comandos por **ADB**.

He intentado con comandos por **ADB** para mover el ratón, pero no creo que sea la mejor práctica ya que no posee de una conexión que esté siempre activa.

Así que me decidí a realizar un programa con la función del mouse de **DeskDock**.

Encontré que **DeskDock** usa: **ADB**, **AdbWinApi**, **AdbWinUsbApi**.

También que tiene un servidor en el lado de la computadora y un cliente en el lado de *Android*. Me imagino que es para poder pasar directamente las señales del ratón.

Comment: Que comandos has intentado del ADB?

Comment: adb shell input touchscreen swipe 1440 2560 1440 2560, tap pero he notado que tiene un tiempo de latencia, asi que no creo que siga fluidamente el mouse si le doy muchos comandos por cada que mueva el mouse